# Can not save transformation changes in Kentico Portal engine - errors in the console

Tags: asp.net, transformation, kentico, portal

I have a running Kentico 11 portal engine site and need to update the transformations in my navigation menu control. Something I have done many times before.

Today I went through all of the steps and the save button does not update the code. It never displays the change were saved messaging.

When I open the browser dev tools I see several errors on the page:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZbBK.png)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check.
Is this happening in different browsers, also?
Can you save other transformations?
On this particular web part, if you select a different transformation, will that save successfully?
And, is the event log registering any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be a caching issue.  What I'd suggest is the following:

- restarting IIS
- Open a private browser window and log in
- attempt to make an edit to the code in question

If this does not resolve the issue, have you made any changes recently to the web.config, in particular the CMSHashstringsalt value?  If so, this will cause your macros to become invalidated.  You'll need to go to System > Macros > Signatures and check both boxes and resign the macros.  It may take some time depending on your site but this could also help resolve your issue.